# CSS footer de-centers page content

Tags: css, center, footer, css-tables

I've been trying very hard to get a sticky footer to work in **all** browsers, for a Wordpress Theme, and I thought I had succeeded... until I realise that a middle table is being pushed to the absolute left of the browser window. The class is still:

```
position:center;
```

So I've guessed that it might be some footer CSS overriding it, but I can't find it! Can I be saved?

[Here's a link](http://sixth-sense.netai.net/) to my temporary site. As you can see, not only are the test posts all to the left, the footer is now also not working as it should! So I've actually made it worse now.
Sorry for all that, I'm not sure what's causing the issue!
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you put     text-align:center; in your #uptop?

The thing is that I would not suggest to embed table in divs since you broke the strict markup rules on the page. And after it is more difficult to find what causes this problems.

Comment: Thanks, but no success. The reason the tables are in divs is for easier separation when I convert this into a WordPress theme. What rules have I broken? (I'm quite new to this)

Comment: sorry my mistake it was just the line alignment on the left side. I thought that the initial table tag is between two div tags. Which one would be the middle part?

Comment: Oops, everything in the "uptop" div. I seem to have forgotten to add a separate div for the main - the header and the test post are all in the same div, but separate tables.

Comment: I've put a link to a temp site, so you can see what I mean. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: If you put a tableStyle class on your tables it will dimension it in the center.
Style: display:block; margin: 0 auto;

Comment: And there are two </div> tags missing. One in front of the downbelow div and one in front of the closing tag of the body. that will solve the footer issue. Applying the style with a table class it will reposition your elements on the center.

Comment: Thanks for that! All sorted, except for the footer, where a spacer table cell is not registering, and the footer is pushed right up to the bottom of a post. Any way to fix this? I think I put all those divs in the right place.

Comment: If you paste your tablstyle comment into a new answer, I'll set it as the accepted solution.